Why doesn't my sim card module with ESP32 connect to network?
After countless hours trying to configure my ESP32 Wrover to communicate with my SIM800L V.2 module I can't find a solution to it failing to connect to the internet.
The IoT SIM card from 1NCE is activated and has worked in my phone. But when powered by the ESP32 from 5V it never connects to the network (LED doesn't blink every 3 seconds as it should).
I can't solve the problem with a multimeter and using an external power supply isn't solving the problem either when trying to increase the amperage suppled.
I'm not sure if it's an electrical or software problem.
Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated. Can also privide photos if required.

"Why ... doesn't work"? We have no idea because you didn't tell/show us how you connect the ESP32 with SIM800L? or what have you tried? The only thing we know is that the slow blink of the LED indicated that it be able to registered to the network.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The simple and painful answer was nothing to do with my electrical set up or configuration with the ESP32.
In Australia 2G and 3G isn't supported. Thus, GSM/GPRS which is used by the SIM800L moduel isn't supported where I live due to running through 2G and 3G.
It's a good idea to thoroughly check the networks which moduels run through and ensure their compatability in your area.
I'm waiting for a SIM7000G to arrive which uses NB-IoT and will hopefully solve my problem.
